# Bazel with Java 11 on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, bazel

I am trying to use Java 11 for my Java Homework. It works fine on my OS X machine, but I have JDK 13 installed on my machine. My instructor uses Ubuntu and does not have the latest java installed. How Can I get Bazel to use JAVA 11 without requiring my instructor to update his JDK.

My .bazelrc is as follows:

```
test --test_output=errors
test --cache_test_results=yes


test --java_toolchain=@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:toolchain_java11
```

And when I run:

```
bazel test java/test/edu/berkeley/cs/util:{hashset,hashmap}
```

I get this wonderfull error.

```
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Writing tracer profile to '/home/tomgrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_tomgrant/75fd013422b9b35862a74918dc983c19/command.profile.gz'
INFO: Analyzed 2 targets (23 packages loaded, 287 targets configured).
INFO: Found 2 test targets...
INFO: Deleting stale sandbox base /home/tomgrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_tomgrant/75fd013422b9b35862a74918dc983c19/sandbox
ERROR: /home/tomgrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_tomgrant/75fd013422b9b35862a74918dc983c19/external/bazel_tools/tools/jdk/BUILD:319:1: Action external/bazel_tools/tools/jdk/platformclasspath.jar failed (Exit 1) java failed: error executing command external/remotejdk11_linux/bin/java -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions '--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.platform=ALL-UNNAMED' -cp ... (remaining 4 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: external/local_jdk
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$SystemModulesLocationHandler.isCurrentPlatform(Locations.java:1862)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$SystemModulesLocationHandler.update(Locations.java:1851)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$SystemModulesLocationHandler.handleOption(Locations.java:1798)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations.handleOption(Locations.java:2062)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.BaseFileManager.handleOption(BaseFileManager.java:269)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.BaseFileManager$2.handleFileManagerOption(BaseFileManager.java:222)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Option.process(Option.java:1138)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Option.handleOption(Option.java:1086)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.BaseFileManager.handleOption(BaseFileManager.java:232)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.doProcessArgs(Arguments.java:390)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.processArgs(Arguments.java:347)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.init(Arguments.java:246)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:185)
    at DumpPlatformClassPath.dumpJDK9AndNewerBootClassPath(DumpPlatformClassPath.java:106)
    at DumpPlatformClassPath.main(DumpPlatformClassPath.java:67)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: external/local_jdk
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.isSameFile(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:333)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.isSameFile(Files.java:1530)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$SystemModulesLocationHandler.isCurrentPlatform(Locations.java:1860)
    ... 14 more
INFO: Elapsed time: 8.063s, Critical Path: 0.26s
INFO: 3 processes: 3 linux-sandbox.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
//java/test/edu/berkeley/cs/util:hashset                              NO STATUS

FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

If anyone can solve this will be glad to send you a bag of Blue Bottle beans or something similar that costs $20 =D

Answer (score 3):

I don't know I understand your question correctly, but I'm looking for the same issue right now.

So far I got one answer from this link from [Bazel Dev](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit/+/master/Documentation/dev-bazel.txt)! from gerrit.googlesource.com

And please look at this section:

[[java-11]]
==== Java 11 support
Java 11 is supported through alternative java toolchain
link:https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/toolchains.html[Bazel option].
To build Gerrit with Java 11, specify JDK 11 java toolchain:

```
$ bazel build \
      --host_javabase=@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:remote_jdk11 \
      --javabase=@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:remote_jdk11 \
      --host_java_toolchain=@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:toolchain_java11 \
      --java_toolchain=@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:toolchain_java11 \
      :release
```

Comment: this finally worked for me, I've been struggling with a Java SpringBoot app for 3 days already because Bazel was compiling with Java 8 and had compatibility issues. FWIW it also works by setting only `java_toolchain` and `javabase`, the other `host_*` are not really required.

Comment: To use these commands with `bazel run`, put them after the target argument, like that: `bazel run //some:target --host_javabase...`.